# How to display icon with openweather api in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openweathermap

I tried to display icon with openweather api.

It work this

```
_else.html.erb
.
.
 <div class="tenki">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png">
.
.
```

but this is only "10d" pattern.
I want to show icon at that time.

so try this..

```
static_pages_controller.rb

.
.
.
 uri = URI.parse("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Tokyo&appid=#{ENV['OPEN_WEATHER_API_KEY']}")
    json = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    res = JSON.parse(json)
    @wind = res['wind']['speed']
    @humidity = res['main']['humidity']
    @clouds = res['clouds']['all']
    @icon = res['weather'][0]['icon']
```

```
_else.html.erb
.
.
 <div class="tenki">
    <h2>Tokyo</h2>
    <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/#{@icon}.png">
.
.
```

but this won' work..
and this is not error so error code is none.
Browser showed only tiny picture which is broken.

Anyone fix it? please teach me.

thank you for reading this.

Comment: For one thing, you're missing a closing quote on the `src` attribute.

Comment: Oh sorry, this is type miss.

Comment: Can you show what the output of the res variable is. Add `p res` to your controller.

Comment: ok!    I add p res in my controller and reload

Comment: Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
{"coord"=>{"lon"=>139.69, "lat"=>35.69}, "weather"=>[{"id"=>803, "main"=>"Clouds", "description"=>"broken clouds", "icon"=>"04n"}], "base"=>"stations", "main"=>{"temp"=>286.98, "feels_like"=>285.08, "temp_min"=>286.48, "temp_max"=>287.15, "pressure"=>1017, "humidity"=>82}, "visibility"=>10000, "wind"=>{"speed"=>3.1, "deg"=>60}, "clouds"=>{"all"=>75}, "dt"=>1588077519, "sys"=>{"type"=>1, "id"=>8074, "country"=>"JP", "sunrise"=>1588017150, "sunset"=>1588065883}, "timezone"=>32400, "id"=>1850144, "name"=>"Tokyo", "cod"=>200}

Comment: Rendering static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered static_pages/_else.html.erb (2.5ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (5.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 1671ms (Views: 1223.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: this message showed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use ERB tags `<%= %>` in order for the parser to actually evaluate the code.

```
<img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/<%= @icon %>.png">
```

The normal string interpolation sequence `#{}` has no special significance in ERB and will just be output as is.

You can also use the image_tag helper:

```
<%= image_tag "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/#{@icon}.png" %>
```